# MODULE FAILURE error while executing ansible script

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I am new to ansible and jenkins .I am using pipeline to  fetch code from git and replace some properties within it using ansible and  I am getting this error while trying to change the properties.

```
  Commit message: "Update replace-property_Gbs.yml"
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // dir
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (replace-property-files)
    [Pipeline] sh
    + ansible-playbook cicd-gbs/replace-property_Gbs.yml -e 'db_ip=localhost db_user=root db_pass=Gbs@2018  db=sf_inventory public_ip=96.126.116.100'
    [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
    the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
    
    PLAY [To replace the correct values in properties file] ************************
    
    TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
    fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "failed_modules": {"setup": {"failed": true, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}}, "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

this is my ANSIBLE SCRIPT in which i am trying to replace some property in code  after fetching it from git through pipeline script

```
---
    - name: To replace the correct values in properties file
      hosts: localhost
      become: true
      vars:
        ip: "{{ db_ip }}"
        user: "{{ db_user }}"
        password: "{{ db_pass }}"
        dbname: "{{ db }}"
        pub_ip: "{{ public_ip }}"
      tasks:
      - name: to remove unwanted properties files for now
        file:
          path: "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd-gbs/cicd-gbs/config-server/src/main/resources/config/{{ item }}"
          state: absent
        with_items:
          - production-service-dev.properties
          - stock-management-service-dev.properties
      - name: To replace the DB Ip on all properties files
        replace:
          path: "{{ item }}"
          regexp: '^spring.datasource.url=*(.+)$'
          replace: "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://{{ ip }}:3306/{{ dbname }}?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true&serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta"
        with_items:
          - '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd-gbs/cicd-gbs/config-server/src/main/resources/config/buyback-service-dev.properties'
      - name: to change the port number on application-propertyfile
        replace:
           path: '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd-gbs/cicd-gbs/config-server/src/main/resources/application.properties'
           regexp: '9090'
           replace: '8821'   
      - name: To replace the db user name
        replace:
          path: "{{ item }}"
          regexp: '^spring.datasource.username=*(.+)$'
          replace: "spring.datasource.username={{ user }}"
        with_items:
          - '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd-gbs/cicd-gbs/config-server/src/main/resources/config/buyback-service-dev.properties'
      - name: To replace the db password
        replace:
          path: "{{ item }}"
          regexp: '^spring.datasource.password=*(.+)$'
          replace: "spring.datasource.password={{ db_pass }}" 
        with_items:
          - '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd-gbs/cicd-gbs/config-server/src/main/resources/config/buyback-service-dev.properties'
      - name: To change the log location
        replace:
          path: "{{ item }}"
          regexp: 'logs'
          replace: '/home/app/jenkinsdeployment'
        with_items:
    server/src/main/resources/config/distribution-service-dev.properties
          - '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd-gbs/cicd-gbs/config-server/src/main/resources/config/buyback-service-dev.properties'
      - name: To change the public ip address on property IP
        replace:
          path: "{{ item }}"
          regexp: '10.16.45.40'
          replace: "{{ pub_ip }}"
        with_items:
          - '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd-gbs/cicd-gbs/config-server/src/main/resources/config/buyback-service-dev.properties'
      - name: To change the port no in bootstrap properties on discovery-gateway service
        replace:
          path: "{{ item }}"
          regexp: '9090'
          replace: "8821"
        with_items:
          - '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd-gbs/cicd-gbs/discovery-gateway/src/main/resources/bootstrap.properties'
      - name: To add the entry for cassendra
        lineinfile:
          path: "{{ item }}"
          regexp: '^spring.data.cassandra.contact-points'
          line: 'spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=localhost'
        with_items:
          - '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd-gbs/cicd-gbs/config-server/src/main/resources/config/buyback-service-dev.properties'
```

Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The error says `sudo: a password is required` so you need to run it with a `sudo ansible-playbook playbook-name` if you running on `localhost`.
- If you are running on remote machine you need to use the following

```yaml
- name: playbook task
  hosts: remote_host
  remote_user: username
  become: true
```

Make sure that `username` has sudo privilege on the remote machine.

Comment: yes it on localhost ... but when i run with sudo ,,,,,, i get the following error ...........We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Comment: do you have `sudo` access on local?

Comment: can you run the playbook with the following argument - `ansible-playbook playbook-name --ask-become-pass` and try?